# Getting Count from condition statement

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach, variable-declaration

I am trying to use a count variable, to count the amount of times the condition is true, and use it for a comparison. but when i compile it, count is always at 0, it never gets incremented, even tho the condition is true.

```
foreach (ReservationType requestReservation in RequestReservation)
{
    List<String> DateList = CreateDateList(requestReservation.StartDate, requestReservation.numDays);

    foreach (Inventory inventory in RoomInventory)
    {
        if (requestReservation.hotelId == inventory.HotelId)
        {
            if (requestReservation.roomType == inventory.RoomType)
            {
                int count = 0;
                int i = 0;
                if (DateList[i] == inventory.Date && inventory.Quantity > 0)
                {
                    count++;

                    if (requestReservation.numDays == count)
                    {
                        requestReservation.reservationId = reservationid;
                        requestReservation.result = ReservationType.ReservationResultType.Success;
                        inventory.Quantity--;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        requestReservation.result = ReservationType.ReservationResultType.RoomNotAvailable;

                    }
                }
            }
        }                      
   }
    reservationid++;
}
```

Comment: `int count = 0;` should be outside foreach loop

Comment: Can you change value at compile time ? interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define `count` outside of the [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx) of the loop

```
int count = 0;
foreach (ReservationType requestReservation in RequestReservation)
{
    List<String> DateList = CreateDateList(requestReservation.StartDate, requestReservation.numDays);
    foreach (Inventory inventory in RoomInventory)
    {
        // Rest of code
    }
}
```

See [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) - The variable is defined just for the scope of the loop and at the end of the scope any reference to it is deleted. By defining it before the loop it is available to the outer scope and any nested scope

Notice that as `count` is defined in the wrong place also when you defined: `int i = 0;` you are actually always checking the same position of `0` in your if statement:

```
//i is always 0
if (DateList[i] == inventory.Date && inventory.Quantity > 0)
```

Comment: I declare i outside the foreach as well, but how do you increment i using this method, or is it better use the for loop to do this?

Comment: @user6875449 - you increase it just the way you did. This isn't a different method just a nested scope.

Comment: yea . now for some reason count =13, when dateList[i] has only 4 elements.and each element in that list, should come out true. so i dont know where the other 9 count are coming from

Comment: @user6875449 - you need to debug and see when and why it is added. Remember that you have 2 loops one inside the other so if you have 3 items in the first collection and 3 in the second it will iterate the rows of the inner loop's scope 9 times.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the count in the loop and it becomes  0 each time declare it out of the loop and it is gonna work

Answer (score 1):

Define count variable before first foreach loop.